# Ошибка в расширении класса ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, adapter

Пытаюсь расширить адаптер для спиннера, написал класс включающий в себя проверку: находится ли в списке данных для спиннера нужная строка:

```
private class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    ArrayList<String> arrayList;

    public myAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, ArrayList objects)
    {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        arrayList = objects;
    }

    public boolean isContains (String text)
    {
        return arrayList.contains(text);
    }
}
```

соответственно  в коде обращаюсь к этому адаптеру таким образом :

```
adapter_2 = new myAdapter(getActivity(),
                            R.layout.spinner_closed, spinner_2_data);
spinner_2.setAdapter(adapter_2);
```

далее мне необходимо в коде провести проверку

```
if (adapter_2.isContains("some_text")) // если в данных для построения листа спиннера есть нужная строка
{
    //some code
}
```

но из кода не получается вызвать метод `isContains()`, кажется, я что то делаю не так, но не могу понять, что именно.

Comment: у вас адаптер в классе с кодом? и сделайте его `public`

Comment: @Jarvis_J да адаптер в классе с кодом

Comment: посмотрите/покажите, какого типа у вас переменная `adapter_2`. Думаю, не `myAdapter`, а `ArrayAdapter`. Надо `my`

Comment: @Jarvis_J точно, сделал myAdapter adapter_2 и в коде теперь могу вызвать нужный метод

Comment: хорошо) Небольшое замечание не в тему: по "соглашению о наименованиях" классы (типа `myAdapter`) принято называть с большой буквы.